# Save/Alphabetize XML Responses in a Foreach Array

Tags: php, xml, sorting, foreach, rss

I'm new to php and am doing this project to teach myself a bit.

I'm importing XML data from a Reuters RSS feed and would like to sort the content of all the responses alphabetically. I've had no problem loading the information I want to the page using a foreach loop, however the sorting system I'm using alphabetizes the words in each xml title individually, as opposed to together as one string.

How can I group or save all the responses together in order to sort them as a whole once they've been collected by the foreach loop?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

function getFeed($feed_url) {

$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$string = $x->channel->item ;

echo "<p>";

foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    $string = $entry->title;
    $split=explode(" ", $string); 
    sort($split); // sorts the elements
    echo implode(" ", $split); //combine and print the elements 
}

echo "</p>";

}?>
```

Comment: Very hard to help without an XML sample as these variables could mean anything! Also, I am interested to see this unique sorting: *alphabetizes the words in each xml title individually, as opposed to together as one string*. So it changes the words in each title?

Comment: The XML doc that I'm using is here: http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/PoliticsNews

Comment: What I mean by alphabetizing the titles together is this:
"administration allow averting change face government immigrate Indian may of Republicans rules shutdown task techies terror that to to tricky Trump Trump U.S. U.S. victims"</br>

As opposed to... 
"Trump administration may change rules that allow terror victims to immigrate to U.S.Indian techies
Trump, Republicans face tricky task of averting U.S. government shutdown"

Comment: I hope that makes sense... I'm new to stack overflow and am struggling with how to format my responses so they're understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting to do is build an array with all the words and then sort it at the end.

```
<?php

function getFeed($feed_url) {    
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    $titles = "";
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $titles .= " $entry->title";
    }
    $split = explode(" ", $titles); 
    sort($split, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_NATURAL);
    return trim(implode(" ", $split));
}

$words = getFeed("http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/PoliticsNews");

echo "<p>$words</p>";
```

I didn't remove non-word characters, so things like quotes will mess with the sorting.

Output:

```
<p>'sanctuary' abuse after announcement, areas as battle California, cards, case crises cut detention drill Egyptian Egyptian-American Exxon financial Florida for freed from funding future give green greets healthcare Homeland hope in in in in Indian looms not of officials orders orders other permission plan possible prevent probe probes racial reboot reform resigns revamped review review review rule rules Russia Security see seeks senator sets slur state summons tax tax testify threatens to to to to Top Trump Trump Trump Trump Trump Trump-Russia Twitter U.S. U.S. U.S. U.S. Uphill visa-holders Waiting Washington will</p>
```

Comment: Ah, this is it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving titles to an array, sort their values, and then iterate back out for `echo` output:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/PoliticsNews");
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

$titles = [];
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    $titles[] = $entry->title;
}

sort($titles, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);   # CASE INSENSITIVE SORT

foreach($titles as $t) {
    echo "<p>". $t ."</p>";
}

# <p>Ex-Illinois Governor Blagojevich's 14-year prison term upheld</p>
# <p>Exxon probe is unconstitutional, Republican prosecutors say</p>
# <p>Group sues Trump for repealing U.S. wildlife rule in rare legal challenge</p>
# <p>Indian techies, IT firms fret as Trump orders U.S. visa review</p>
# <p>Trump, Republicans face tricky task of averting U.S. government shutdown</p>
# <p>Trump administration may change rules that allow terror victims to immigrate to U.S.</p>
# <p>U.S. House committee sets more hearings in Trump-Russia probe</p>
# <p>U.S. judicial panel finds Texas hurt Latino vote with redrawn boundaries</p>
# <p>U.S. retailers bet on Congress over Bolivia to thwart Trump  border tax issue</p>
# <p>U.S. Treasury's Mnuchin: Trump to order reviews of financial rules</p>
```